# How I can calculate the timeframe between row n and row n+1 in Powerquery?

Tags: excel, powerquery

[image: Problem context]

I wonder if there is a way to get a second table ex:

5/4/2020   0:00 -> Duration of the 1st event

5/5/2020   9:16 -> Duration of the 2st event

Where each durantion of the event is given by calculating the difference between time n and time n+1.

Comment: Where is 05/05/2020 09:16 coming from in that sample data?

Also - please post data as a table, rather than a screenshot.

Comment: To refer to the next or previous row, you can either use an Index column or you can add a "shifted" column.  Then it is just a matter of subtraction and returning whatever data type you prefer. Can't know that since you provide no information, nor do you show what you have tried. To make your data useful **edit your question** to post it as **text**, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).  *Enter the output of the generator as **code.***  Also post an example of the expected output **from your sample data** (that can be a screenshot).

Comment: n+1 refers to the next row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below

I assume the first column is a text formatted column that can be split on a space to get the numbers at the end

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Custom", type date}, {"Hour", Int64.Type}, {"Day of Week", Int64.Type}}),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", "Copy"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Duplicated Column", "Copy", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Column1.1", "dur1"}),
// pull row above into current row
    shiftedList = {null} & List.RemoveLastN(#"Split Column by Delimiter"[dur1],1),
    custom1 = Table.ToColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter") & {shiftedList},
    custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(#"Split Column by Delimiter") & {"Prev Row"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(custom2,{{"dur1", type duration}, {"Prev Row", type duration}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Custom.1", each [dur1]-[Prev Row]),
Alternate=Table.AlternateRows(#"Added Custom",0,1,1),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Alternate,{"dur1", "Prev Row", "Column1.1"}),
#"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Custom.1", type duration}})
in #"Changed Type2"
```

[image]

| Column1 | Custom | Hour | Day of Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/4/2022 23:40 | 5/4/2022 | 23 | 3 |
| 5/4/2022 23:40 | 5/4/2022 | 23 | 3 |
| 5/5/2022 0:07 | 5/5/2022 | 0 | 4 |
| 5/5/2022 9:23 | 5/5/2022 | 9 | 4 |
| 5/5/2022 9:23 | 5/5/2022 | 9 | 4 |
| 5/5/2022 9:30 | 5/5/2022 | 9 | 4 |